# How to make deep copy on list of maps in dart?

Tags: dart

How can i make deep copy on List of Maps in dart ? .  Here is the code i have tried :

```
void main() {
  List<Map> arr1 = [
    {'f1': 1, 'f2': 2}
  ];
  List<Map> arr2 = [...arr1];
  arr2[0]["f1"] = 11;
  print("$arr1 $arr2");
}
```

I expect `arr1[0]["f1"]` to be `1` not `11`.

Comment: Sorry if i have confused anyone  . I want to make deep copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to deep-copy data structures.

If you know the type, then it's fairly easy:

```dart
var copy = [for (var e in original) ...e];
```

That is, use `for`/`in` on each level until the last, then spread that.

A general function which does deep-copying of list/map structures is probably impossible to write. The big problem is that there is no available way to create a new `Map` with the same type arguments as an existing map, based only on the *run-time* type of the existing map. There is a `toList` on `List`, which can create a list of the same type, but no `toMap` on `Map`. Because of that, you need to write the copy operation so that it matches the actual type that you want to copy, and you can't do that generically.

Comment: thank you for your help your answer helped me.
   ```List arr2 = [for (var e in arr1) {...e} ] ```